# Where to put total() for an entity object in the OOP way that easy to use in presentation?

Tags: oop

I've a trivial OOP-related question that puzzle me: In `Invoice` class, there is a `total()` method that will perform calculation and return the resulting calculation.  When coding  presentation layer, specifically the 'Add New Invoice' screen, I need to display the `total()` of the `Invoice` while user is entering its data.  At this point, because this is a 'Add New' screen, I don't have a `Invoice` object yet which I planned to create after user click the 'Save' button.  Data entered by user is still stored in view model (value of text field, combo box, etc).

No `Invoice` object means I can't call `total()` to display total in progress while user entering invoice's data.  But from what I learned from OOP books, the `total()` method should belong to `Invoice` class.

What is the better design without changing the requirements on presentation layer: screen should display temporary total while user entering new invoice's data?

Comment: According to my understanding, during submission of the the Invoice form, update the Invoice object and the total vale, store that value in a variable(last_updated_total). While loading the UI/Invoice form for the next time just call a function which will return the last_updated_total value. This function will act as an message passing interface to the Presentation layer.

Comment: I need to display a real time `total()` value while user typing at text field or selecting combobox. User entered values are still in presentation layer and are not final yet. User haven't submit the form yet.  I can just copy `Invoice.total()` source code to presentation layer's controller, but that will causes duplication.

Comment: You have to keep something as buffer, In that buffer update only those fields from the Invoice form which requires real time calculation. On gaining focus on each item, read and manipulate data from the buffer and show it in UI. You have to maintain an intermidiate layer for communication between the View and Calculation.

Comment: Do you mean, in OOP way, I shouldn't put `total()` as a method of `Invoice' class?

Comment: It depends, if you are using total() only for this purpose, then no need to keep it, you can easily get the status from the getXX() for each item of the UI,which you can update on Save() click. You can keep a function like buffer() which will contain the act as the intermidiate layer for communication and it will update the data when the user is going to fill the UI, but that data will not be reflected in the Invoice object. It will only be saved after clicking Save button in UI. You can also optimise a lot inside.

Comment: I don't think that is a good idea, it will hard to maintain these 'intermediate' in the future.  @Jon has a good answer but it requires me to setup event-handler for every component in the form to acts as binders, or use a MVVM framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer kind of points to itself: you need to have an `Invoice` model even when adding a new one. The viewmodel is not supposed to work without a backing model; it's should be an *intermediate* layer that provides convenience.

Comment: I'm going to create the `Invoice` object after user submit the form (click 'Save' button).  But I need to display real-time `total()` from an `Invoice` value while user typing in a text field or selecting combobox. Inputs from user are not final yet, so I stored them in view model.  Do you mean I should directly store the inputs to a new `Invoice` instance as soon as user type in text field?

Comment: @DavidBower: Yes. A viewmodel cannot ever exist without a model to back it up. So there has to be a model, but in this case it will be one that has not been saved yet.

Comment: This answers my question, although it requires me to setup event-handler for every component in the form to acts as binders, or use a MVVM framework.